# sending 404 status but browser displays 500 error at client side

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, http-status-codes

I am trying to send http 404 status code based on a IF condition. But, at client end I am seeing http 500 error. 
In my apach2 error logs, I am seeing malformed headers. 
Having looked at my code on number of times, I couldn’t figure out what went wrong! 
Can anyone please suggest me how to send 404 message to client?

Below is my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use File::Copy qw( copy );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use HTTP::Status qw(:constants :is status_message);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
use File::Basename;
use URI;



my $extfile = '/home/suresh/clientrequest.txt';
open(FH, ">>$extfile") or die "Cannot open file";
my $query = CGI->new;
my $stcode = status_message(200);
my $uri =$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
my $rdate =strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", localtime());
print FH "Got Following Headers:\n";
print FH $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'}, "\n";
my $dir  = '/home/suresh/Assets/';
my $nffFile = fileparse ("$uri", qr/\.[^.]*/);
my $fullFname = $nffFile . ".nff";
my $path = catfile($dir, $fullFname);
print FH "fullname:", $fullFname, "\n";

#Search requested asset files
opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files = readdir(DIR);
if (grep($_=~/$fullFname/,@files)){
print FH "Found the file: ", $fullFname, "\n";
open my $fh, '<:raw', $path;
print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 200 $stcode";
print $query->header(
        -'Date'=> $rdate,
        -'Content-Type'=>'application/octet-stream',
        -'Connection'=>'Keep-Alive',
        -'attachment'=>$path,
    );
binmode STDOUT, ':raw';

 copy $fh => \*STDOUT;
    close $fh
        or die "Cannot close '$path': $!";

}else {
        $stcode = status_message(404);
        print "$ENV{'SERVER_PROTOCOL'} 404 $stcode\n";
        print $query->header(
        -'Server'=>$ENV{'SERVER_SOFTWARE'},
        -'Content-type'=>'text/plain',
        );
        }
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: why -ve vote ? Please give reasons if you have -ve voted.

Answer (score 5):

You should be printing the headers *first*, before anything else. Otherwise, the browser won't know how to handle what you're sending to it. Instead of this:

```
print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 200 $stcode";
print $query->header( ... );
```

do this:

```
print $query->header( ... );
print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 200 $stcode";
```

Also, you can specify an HTTP status code using CGI.pm:

```
print $query->header( -status => '404 Not Found' );
```

A little tip for debugging CGI applications: change

```
use Carp;
```

to

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

This will display fatal errors directly in the browser so you don't have to hunt around in your webserver logs. However, do **NOT** leave the `fatalsToBrowser` option enabled in production code, as it can reveal the inner workings of your application to attackers.

Comment: Thanks !! The line print $query->header( -status => '404 Not Found' ); did the trick and it worked!! . Interestingly ..the status line when kept before headers works only for status 200 and doesn’t for other status codes !